# averaging list of lists python column-wise

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:
something like:

```
data = [[240, 240, 239],
        [250, 249, 237], 
        [242, 239, 237],
        [240, 234, 233]]
```

And I want to average this out like

```
[average_column_1, average_column_2, average_column_3]
```

My piece of code is like not very elegant.
It is the naive way of going thru the list, keeping the sum in seperate container and then dividing by number of  elements.

I think there is a pythonic way to do this.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Pure Python:

```
from __future__ import division
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)
a = [[240, 240, 239],
     [250, 249, 237], 
     [242, 239, 237],
     [240, 234, 233]]
print map(mean, zip(*a))
```

printing

```
[243.0, 240.5, 236.5]
```

NumPy:

```
a = numpy.array([[240, 240, 239],
                 [250, 249, 237], 
                 [242, 239, 237],
                 [240, 234, 233]])
print numpy.mean(a, axis=0)
```

Python 3:

```
from statistics import mean
a = [[240, 240, 239],
     [250, 249, 237], 
     [242, 239, 237],
     [240, 234, 233]]
print(*map(mean, zip(*a)))
```

Comment: Preferable with `from itertools import imap, izip`

Comment: @ms4py: `from future_builtins import map, zip` if you decide to go this route

Comment: +1 neat .. looking at the first solution is just proof how how sleek Python code can be

Comment: `map` isn't "pythonic" in any way, and who needs `numpy` here? And *this* is the accepted answer?

Comment: @BlaXpirit: The NumPy solution is easier to read, more concise, faster and uses less memory, so I mentioned it for people who are using NumPy anyway.  And why do you think `map()` exists, and still exists in Python 3.x?

Comment: @OlehPrypin is right in that this solution doesn't work in python 3 because `map` now returns `<map object at 0x7f84c80b9780>`.  The more portable and pythonic answer is by Andrew Clark.  But having a fast numpy answer is handy.

Comment: @nealmcb OlehPrypin never said that the solution doesn't work in Python 3.  And it actually does still work, since you would usually want to iterate over the averages, not just print the list.  The Python core developers deliberately kept `map()` as a built-in in Python 3, while other functional programming functions were dropped (`apply()`) or moved into a module (`reduce()`).  It makes for concise and readable code.

Answer (score 32):

```
data = [[240, 240, 239],
        [250, 249, 237], 
        [242, 239, 237],
        [240, 234, 233]]
avg = [float(sum(col))/len(col) for col in zip(*data)]
# [243.0, 240.5, 236.5]
```

This works because `zip(*data)` will give you a list with the columns grouped, the `float()` call is only necessary on Python 2.x, which uses integer division unless `from __future__ import division` is used.

Comment: I believe this answer is the best. It was also the first.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: There is far too much emphasis on speed on SO – the important thing should be quality.  Also note that this answer came third (or fourth, if we count the deleted answer).

Answer (score 15):

Use `zip()`, like so:

```
averages = [sum(col) / float(len(col)) for col in zip(*data)]
```

`zip()` takes multiple iterable arguments, and returns slices of those iterables (as tuples), until one of the iterables cannot return anything more. In effect, it performs a transpose operation, akin to matrices.

```
>>> data = [[240, 240, 239],
...         [250, 249, 237], 
...         [242, 239, 237],
...         [240, 234, 233]]

>>> [list(col) for col in zip(*data)]
[[240, 250, 242, 240],
 [240, 249, 239, 234],
 [239, 237, 237, 233]]
```

By performing `sum()` on each of those slices, you effectively get the column-wise sum. Simply divide by the length of the column to get the mean.

Side point: In Python 2.x, division on integers floors the decimal by default, which is why `float()` is called to "promote" the result to a floating point type.

Comment: Don't forget to divide by the length ;)

Comment: Worth adding an explanation: `zip` is a function that takes multiple sequences and returns tuples on a "column-by-column" basis. So it returns (x[0][0], x[1][0], x[2][0]) then (x[1][0], x[1][1], x[1][2]) and so on. It will stop retrieving as soon as it runs out of items for a given line, however.  It's easier to diagram in code, care to show how it works?

Answer (score 10):

```
import numpy as np

data = [[240, 240, 239],
        [250, 249, 237], 
        [242, 239, 237],
        [240, 234, 233]]

np.mean(data, axis=0)
# array([ 243. ,  240.5,  236.5])
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` and `zip`:

```
list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), zip(*data)))
```

```
[243.0, 240.5, 236.5]
```