# How to calculate the mean, if my list it was with another list inside?

Tags: python, list

I create a list in python with 17 other lists inside. See the exemple:

```
[[3.29588, 3.14241, 2.53874, 1.87257, 1.01365, 0.844504, 0.761601, 1.28007, 1.95795, 2.33491, 3.21032, 3.6976], 
[3.74857, 3.4343, 2.97245, 1.7386, 0.931359, 0.82109, 0.840537, 1.46436, 1.75026, 2.467, 3.36575, 3.6428], 
[3.2517, 3.37892, 2.84753, 1.7375, 1.11921, 0.761399, 0.780625, 1.40971, 1.80878, 2.49257, 3.0503, 3.22026], 
[4.86471, 3.95591, 3.31745, 2.16819, 1.40167, 0.962902, 1.01542, 1.56245, 2.2488, 3.30197, 3.78625, 4.16218], 
[4.37859, 3.58889, 2.18892, 1.85142, 1.36302, 1.04413, 1.14967, 1.63279, 2.06895, 3.36799, 3.64174, 4.00779], 
[3.78213, 2.85967, 2.29597, 2.0755, 1.32856, 1.07074, 1.05019, 1.43226, 2.01495, 2.96983, 4.20358, 3.97129], 
[4.11538, 2.98188, 2.51697, 1.81049, 1.23526, 0.982138, 1.09718, 1.55118, 2.42966, 3.4746, 3.70046, 4.6149], 
[4.28626, 4.00553, 3.36899, 2.40897, 1.40696, 0.961761, 0.881263, 1.25325, 2.05434, 2.54193, 4.13187, 4.60115], 
[4.15797, 3.16266, 3.31037, 2.16276, 1.42262, 0.924327, 1.11161, 1.57012, 2.21882, 2.94404, 4.18211, 4.19463], 
[3.94132, 3.74934, 3.52944, 1.98444, 1.33248, 0.974261, 0.976807, 1.63763, 1.96279, 3.17012, 2.96314, 4.23448], 
[4.21067, 4.1027, 3.48602, 2.26189, 1.36373, 1.06551, 1.06262, 1.24214, 2.11701, 3.19951, 3.83816, 4.18072], 
[4.52377, 4.02346, 3.10936, 2.41148, 1.44596, 1.03784, 0.997611, 1.66809, 2.2909, 3.13247, 4.07816, 3.4008], 
[2.40782, 3.18881, 2.95376, 1.84203, 1.28495, 0.957945, 1.03246, 1.80852, 2.15366, 2.74635, 4.26849, 4.12046], 
[4.48346, 3.81883, 2.96019, 2.34712, 1.33384, 1.01678, 1.09052, 1.44302, 2.18529, 3.29472, 3.90009, 4.67098], 
[4.34282, 4.45031, 3.55955, 2.35169, 1.44429, 1.02647, 1.24539, 1.73125, 2.3716, 3.3476, 4.21021, 4.11485], 
[4.5259, 4.21495, 3.26138, 2.38399, 1.55304, 1.21289, 1.17101, 1.79027, 2.24747, 3.03854, 3.31494, 3.70687], 
[4.47717, 4.6265, 3.10359, 2.15151, 1.26597, 0.886686, 1.18106, 1.67292, 2.45298, 3.21713, 4.20611, 4.35356], 
[4.10159, 3.83354, 2.95835, 1.65168, 1.26774, 0.846464, 0.943836, 1.49787, 2.01609, 2.84914, 3.47291, 3.63075]]
```

How i create a mean to each elemento of this lists. i need take the first element of each list and calculate the mean, after i need take the second element of each list and calculate the mean... And this for each one of the twelve elements of this list. In the end, i'll have just one list, with 12 elements, that represent the mean of the twelve elements of each list.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [averaging list of lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919664/averaging-list-of-lists-python)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (`lst` is your list of lists):

```
means = [sum(sublst[i] for sublst in lst) / len(lst) for i in range(len(lst[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `zip` functions would be appropriate here:

```
list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), zip(*lst)))
```

```
[4.049761666666666,
 3.695478333333333,
 3.015501666666667,
 2.067323888888889,
 1.3063504999999997,
 0.9665465000000002,
 1.0216338888888887,
 1.5359944444444444,
 2.130572222222222,
 2.993912222222222,
 3.7513661111111114,
 4.029226111111111]
```

You could also use `statistics.mean`:

```
from statistics import mean

list(map(mean, zip(*lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[3.29588, 3.14241, 2.53874, 1.87257, 1.01365, 0.844504, 0.761601, 1.28007, 1.95795, 2.33491, 3.21032, 3.6976], [3.74857, 3.4343, 2.97245, 1.7386, 0.931359, 0.82109, 0.840537, 1.46436, 1.75026, 2.467, 3.36575, 3.6428], [3.2517, 3.37892, 2.84753, 1.7375, 1.11921, 0.761399, 0.780625, 1.40971, 1.80878, 2.49257, 3.0503, 3.22026], [4.86471, 3.95591, 3.31745, 2.16819, 1.40167, 0.962902, 1.01542, 1.56245, 2.2488, 3.30197, 3.78625, 4.16218], [4.37859, 3.58889, 2.18892, 1.85142, 1.36302, 1.04413, 1.14967, 1.63279, 2.06895, 3.36799, 3.64174, 4.00779], [3.78213, 2.85967, 2.29597, 2.0755, 1.32856, 1.07074, 1.05019, 1.43226, 2.01495, 2.96983, 4.20358, 3.97129], [4.11538, 2.98188, 2.51697, 1.81049, 1.23526, 0.982138, 1.09718, 1.55118, 2.42966, 3.4746, 3.70046, 4.6149], [4.28626, 4.00553, 3.36899, 2.40897, 1.40696, 0.961761, 0.881263, 1.25325, 2.05434, 2.54193, 4.13187, 4.60115], [4.15797, 3.16266, 3.31037, 2.16276, 1.42262, 0.924327, 1.11161, 1.57012, 2.21882, 2.94404, 4.18211, 4.19463], [3.94132, 3.74934, 3.52944, 1.98444, 1.33248, 0.974261, 0.976807, 1.63763, 1.96279, 3.17012, 2.96314, 4.23448], [4.21067, 4.1027, 3.48602, 2.26189, 1.36373, 1.06551, 1.06262, 1.24214, 2.11701, 3.19951, 3.83816, 4.18072], [4.52377, 4.02346, 3.10936, 2.41148, 1.44596, 1.03784, 0.997611, 1.66809, 2.2909, 3.13247, 4.07816, 3.4008], [2.40782, 3.18881, 2.95376, 1.84203, 1.28495, 0.957945, 1.03246, 1.80852, 2.15366, 2.74635, 4.26849, 4.12046], [4.48346, 3.81883, 2.96019, 2.34712, 1.33384, 1.01678, 1.09052, 1.44302, 2.18529, 3.29472, 3.90009, 4.67098], [4.34282, 4.45031, 3.55955, 2.35169, 1.44429, 1.02647, 1.24539, 1.73125, 2.3716, 3.3476, 4.21021, 4.11485], [4.5259, 4.21495, 3.26138, 2.38399, 1.55304, 1.21289, 1.17101, 1.79027, 2.24747, 3.03854, 3.31494, 3.70687], [4.47717, 4.6265, 3.10359, 2.15151, 1.26597, 0.886686, 1.18106, 1.67292, 2.45298, 3.21713, 4.20611, 4.35356], [4.10159, 3.83354, 2.95835, 1.65168, 1.26774, 0.846464, 0.943836, 1.49787, 2.01609, 2.84914, 3.47291, 3.63075]]

avgs = []
cnts = []

N = len(a)
M = len(a[0])

# initialize arrays
for i in range(0, M):
    avgs.append(0)
    cnts.append(0)

# update averages
for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
        cnts[j] += 1
        avgs[j] += a[i][j]
    
# divide by count
for i in range(0, M):
    avgs[i] /= cnts[i]

# print averages
print(avgs)
```